# Problemas al usar un constructor

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación windows forms, en la cual uso ninject, el problema es que en el constructor de mi userControl implemento para usar mis operaciones CRUD.

```
public partial class ucProveedor : UserControl, ICommandAction
{
    private ISaProveedor _repositoryProveedor; 
    public ucProveedor(ISaProveedor repositoryProveedor)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _repositoryProveedor = repositoryProveedor;
    }
 }
```

Entonces cuando llamo al userControl me pide un parámetro.

```
private void btnMenuProveedor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ucProveedor _proveedor = new ucProveedor();
    pnlPiso.Controls.Add(_proveedor);
}
```

¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: si usas Ninject no puedes hacer un new de la instancia de ucProveedor, debes resolverlo mediente el metodo Resolve() de IoC container (o sea ninject) ya que este es quien sabe como inyectar la instancia del constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas `Ninject` no puedes hacer un `new` de la instancia de ucProveedor, debe resolverlo mediente el metodo `Get<>()` de IoC container (o sea ninject) ya que este es quien sabe como inyectar la instancia del constructor.

[Dependency Injection in WinForms using Ninject and Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127763/dependency-injection-in-winforms-using-ninject-and-entity-framework)

Podrias ayudarte con la libreria

[ninject.extensions.infrastructure](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ninject.extensions.infrastructure.winforms)

La idea es que puedas definir el

```
Kernel.Bind<ISaProveedor>().To<ClassConcreta_SaProveedor>();
Kernel.Bind<ucProveedor>().To<ucProveedor>();
```

Para luego poder usar

```
ucProveedor _proveedor = kernel.Get<ucProveedor>();
```

como obtienes la instancia usando a niject de factory este asignara en el constructor la instancia que necesita

**Nota:** no estoy muy seguro si ninject permite mapar una clase concreta con su misma clase, pero solo es cuestion de probarlo.

Comment: Leandro, gracias por la información, lo resolvi usando esto var _proveedor = CompositionRoot.Resolve<ucProveedor>();